# Reused xib with storyboard (add UIView to UINavigationcontroller)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, xib

I have one xib contain some controllers. how to add `UIView` to `UINavigationcontroller` programmatically.

can you please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to drag and drop `UIView` in your IB and outlet it and set

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = youroutletview;
```

[image]

Now you can customize view as you want.